# Add negative values for CreateWindow macro in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I created the textbox using *CreateWindow* API in Windows GUI Programming as follows,

```
CreateWindow( TEXT("EDIT"),
            TEXT(""),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_DLGFRAME | ES_RIGHT,
            x, y, w, h,
            hwnd_,
            (HMENU)0,
            GetWindowInstance( hwnd_ ),
            0 );
```

When I use **ES_NUMBER** edit control style, it is only allowed to put digits into the edit control. But I cannot put negative values as *-123*.

Is there way to support to only integers within negative values in edit control?
Can any one help for that me?

Comment: See if this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-control-styles) is helpful.

Comment: According to above documentation, we can only add digits when we are using ES_NUMBER. Is there way to add a support for negative values also?

Comment: `To translate text that was entered into the edit control to an integer value, use the GetDlgItemInt function. `   [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemint) of GetDlgItemInt function states that you need to set a `bSigned` flag which `Indicates whether the function should examine the text for a minus sign at the beginning and return a signed integer value if it finds one`

Comment: It is a simplistic style option that filters the characters you type.  Only digits are allowed, so not "-".  Don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ES_NUMBER style should be better called ES_DIGITSONLY. It accepts only digits as keyboard input.

If you want to use the Windows edit control accepting digits and signs, you have to subclass it. 
That means, you exchange the default window procedure of your edit control with your own window procedure. Your window procedure implements the new features of the edit control, anything else is passed to the default window procedure of the edit control (not DefWindowProc() !).

Here is an example in old-style C (because you used the Win32 API):

```
WNDPROC PreviousEditProc;

LRESULT  CALLBACK EditSubclassProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {

const TCHAR* ACCEPTED_CHARS = TEXT("0123456789+-");
TCHAR    c;

    switch( uMessage ) {
        case WM_CHAR:
            c = (TCHAR) wParam;
            if( _tcschr( ACCEPTED_CHARS, c ) == nullptr )
                return( 0 );
            break;
    } 

    return( CallWindowProc( PreviousEditProc, hWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam ) );
}
```

The subclass the edit control, you have to change to window procedure and save the previous procedure:

```
HWND hEdit;

hEdit = CreateWindow( TEXT("EDIT"),
            TEXT(""),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_DLGFRAME | ES_RIGHT,
            x, y, w, h,
            hwnd_,
            (HMENU)0,
            GetWindowInstance( hwnd_ ),
            0 );
PreviousEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong( hEdit, GWL_WNDPROC, (LPARAM) EditSubclassProc );
```

Remarks:

Your may subclass several edit controls, using the code above, but you cannot subclass an edit control twice with the same subclass procedure (PreviousEditProc will be overwritten by itself).

The TCHAR type is wchar_t, if you compile your project with Unicode enabled or
char else. You may want to use char or wchar_t directly.

The string literal ACCEPTED_CHARS contains all acceppted characters. For a longer list you may use isdigit(), ischar() etc. instead of the _tcsstr() function.

Comment: It still has the exact same problem as ES_NUMBER, you can copy/paste anything you want.

Comment: In this case _Backspace_ character is ignored. Also copy/paste is not working.